# Set Time Constraint for generated URL of uploaded files

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to build an application (using Django) which uploads files and generates corresponding URL. Is there some way we can set time constraint for the url, i.e. the uploaded file in url should exist only for little time after the specified time that url should give an error.
I would be using the default django server, in such a case what would be the possible ways to tackle the time constarint problem. I would be glad if you answer for both the cases as for global and individual files, or even a single solution is good :) 
~Newbie up with a Herculean Task! Thank You :)

Comment: You have to set `expiry date` in your model for that uploaded file and user .

Comment: @PriyankPatel How would you set expiry date for each and every file and user. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a datetimefield as an additional column and expire it as and when required.

Answer (score 1):

If your uploaded files are being served by the Django app itself, then it's quite easy (and can be solved in different ways depending on weither the "time constraint" is global to all files/urls or not).

Else - that is if the files are served by Apache or anything similar - you'll have to resort to some async mechanism to collect and delete "obsolete" files, either the Q&D way (using a cron job) or with some help from Celery.